# How to set output console width in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I build and run my C++ code from Visual Studio 2013, the console window width is un-adjustable and because of this, causes my output to be pushed onto the next line sooner than I'd like.

How can I get Visual Studio to make the console window width larger?

If I need to insert code in my application to do this, is there a way I can put a compile-time check so that it removes the code when not compiling on Windows? I'm trying to make the code as portable as possible.

Comment: Can't you right click on the title bar of the window and use the edit menu to set the size? It should keep that even after a rebuild of your application.

Comment: Ah. That worked! For portability reasons, I think this is the best solution. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 25):

One solution that I use frequently with console applications I debug from Visual Studio that does not require code changes is to do the following:

1. Right Click on title bar of your running console application
2. Select Properties
3. Select Layout
4. Then set the window size.

After you close the dialog box, Windows should save the settings or prompt you to save depending on your version of Windows. I believe Windows 8 or newer does not prompt, while Windows 7 or lower prompts.

Answer (score 14):

1. Use `Console::SetWindowSize()` method (under .NET framework).

   You can refer to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setwindowsize(v=vs.110).aspx) for its documentation and code examples.
2. Or you can use `MoveWindow()` method (you can also move the window):

   ```
   #include <windows.h>
   using namespace std;
   int main (void)
   {
       HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
       RECT r;
       GetWindowRect(console, &r); //stores the console's current dimensions

       MoveWindow(console, r.left, r.top, 800, 100, TRUE); // 800 width, 100 height

       // ...
   }
   ```

   Check out [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1481/) for more information.

---

If you really want to make your code as portable as possible, maybe you should manually set it by running a `cmd` prompt. Click on the icon at the top. Select `defaults`. Enter the settings you want.

Comment: What #include do I need for that to work? And how can I made it NOT get compiled in when building the code on say GCC? (like a via a macro or something?)

Comment: @Michael Or simply, you can follow drescherjm's suggestion to change it under the edit menu.

Comment: @Michael See updated. You just need to `#include <windows.h>` to make it work for the second method.

Comment: ah you're right. I think for portability reasons I should do what @drescherjm suggested and have it set via the console properties. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use this:

```
Console.WindowWidth = Console.LargestWindowWidth - [insert number of pixels from the end of the screen]
Console.WindowHeight = Console.LargestWindowHeight - [insert number of pixels from the end of the screen]
```

If I wanted to set the console window to be 15 pixels from the edge of the screen, I would do this:

```
Console.WindowWidth = Console.LargestWindowWidth - 15
```

Comment: As a note, `LargestWindowHeight` and `LargestWindowWidth` are actually numbers of rows and columns the console window can support, not pixel counts. So subtracting 15 actually subtracts 15 columns of space, not 15 pixels. Just sharing for anyone stumbling across this in the future.

Comment: This answer applies only to C++CLI and .NET applications.

Comment: @JimFell I've never used C++ CLI and this worked perfectly fine for me. Perhaps the spec has been updated since I posted this answer to remove the functionality?