# Setting the Console Window size and Buffer Size in c++ (win32 app)

Tags: c++

I have a big problem, at least for me... 
(I apologize in advance for my english, i'm still studying it at school )
I've made a simple "Snake" game in c++ using windows.h for the graphics, manipulating the screen buffer manually instead of using std::cout, because it's really slow..
The game work just fine, it's not a game logic problem, it's a terminal problem... (I'm using VS 2015)

Here is the complete code of the program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <list>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

int nScreenWidth = 60;
int nScreenHeight = 63;

int main()
{
    wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight];
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

// MAIN LOOP ----------
while (1)
{
    // RESET POINT ----------
    bool bKeyLeft = false;
    bool bKeyRight = false;
    bool bKeyLeftOld = false;
    bool bKeyRightOld = false;

    struct sSnakeSegment {
        int posx;
        int posy;
    };

    list<sSnakeSegment> snake = {
        { 30,30 },
        { 31,30 },
        { 32,30 },
        { 33,30 },
        { 34,30 },
        { 35,30 },
        { 36,30 }
    };

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    bool isDead = false;
    int fx = 20;
    int fy = 30;
    int score = 0;

    int nSnakeDirection = 3; // 0 = north (Clockwise)

    while(!isDead)
    {
        // TIMING ----------
        auto t1 = chrono::system_clock::now();
        while ((chrono::system_clock::now() - t1) < 200ms)
        {
            // INPUT ----------
            bKeyRight = (0x8000 & GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned char)('\x27'))) != 0;
            bKeyLeft = (0x8000 & GetAsyncKeyState((unsigned char)('\x25'))) != 0;

            if (bKeyRight && !bKeyRightOld)
            {
                nSnakeDirection++;
                if (nSnakeDirection == 4) nSnakeDirection = 0;
            }

            if (bKeyLeft && !bKeyLeftOld)
            {
                nSnakeDirection--;
                if (nSnakeDirection == -1) nSnakeDirection = 3;
            }

            bKeyRightOld = bKeyRight;
            bKeyLeftOld = bKeyLeft;
        }
        // ===== GAME LOGIC =====

        // HEAD CREATION ----------
        switch (nSnakeDirection)
        {
        case 0: //UP
            snake.push_front({ snake.front().posx , snake.front().posy - 1 });
            break;
        case 1: //RIGHT
            snake.push_front({ snake.front().posx + 1 , snake.front().posy });
            break;
        case 2: //DOWN
            snake.push_front({ snake.front().posx , snake.front().posy + 1 });
            break;
        case 3: //LEFT
            snake.push_front({ snake.front().posx - 1 , snake.front().posy });
            break;
        }

        // SNAKE VS FOOD
        if (snake.front().posx == fx && snake.front().posy == fy)
        {
            while (screen[fy * nScreenWidth + fx] != L' ')
            {
                fx = rand() % nScreenWidth;
                fy = (rand() % (nScreenHeight - 3)) + 3;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                snake.push_back({ snake.back().posx, snake.back().posy });
        }

        // TAIL CHOPPING
        snake.pop_back();

        // TITLE DISPLAY ----------
        for (x = 0; x < nScreenWidth; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < nScreenHeight; y++)
            {
                screen[y*nScreenWidth + x] = ' ';
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth; i++)
        {
            screen[i] = L'=';
            screen[2 * nScreenWidth + i] = L'=';
        }
        wsprintf(&screen[nScreenWidth + 10], L" simncstrn@gmail.com   ! S N A K E !");
        // SNAKE DISPLAY ----------
        for (auto s : snake)
        {
            screen[s.posy * nScreenWidth + s.posx] = isDead ? L'+' : L'O';
        }
        screen[snake.front().posy * nScreenWidth + snake.front().posx] = isDead ? L'@' : L'#';
        // FOOD DISPLAY ----------
        screen[fy * nScreenWidth + fx] = L'F';

        // SCREEN WRITING   
        screen[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight] = '\0';
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

The game is not even completed, it is missing some functionality.
The problem come when launching the app. The Console open in 120x40 mode by default (both buffer and window) and with a different charachter, and my game map is 60x63 (3 for the title), so i have to manually right click on the window and set the options manually. But i want to do this automatically. Is there a way to do this? I've actually searched for similar question, but they where not working for me. I tried, for example, to use the SetConsoleWindowInfo() function, but it didnt seem to work, maybe i'm using it wrong..

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: See `MoveWindow()` solution in [How to set output console width in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238806/how-to-set-output-console-width-in-visual-studio)